# Reference Request: Characters of Finite General Linear Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra, reference-request, representation-theory, characters

I've been looking at J.A. Green's article [The Characters of Finite General Linear Groups](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1955-080-02/S0002-9947-1955-0072878-2/S0002-9947-1955-0072878-2.pdf) and it seems that Green in this article comes up with a way of calculating all irreducible characters of a given general linear group over a finite field $GL_n(\mathbb{F}_q)$, where $q$ is a prime power.

The article is quite old though, and really tough to read. Would anyone happen to know a more recent or more easily digestible source for this material?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I hope that following references help you:

**1**.M.R Darafsheh, On some characters of $GL_n(\mathbb F)$, J Pure and Apple Algebra, 1985, 247-252.

**2**.R. Gow, Some characters of Affine subgroup of classical linear group, j London math Soc, 1976, 231-238.

**3**.R. Gow, Properties of the characters of the finite general linear groups related to transpose-inverse involution, Proc London Math Soc, 1983, 493-506.

**4**.A.O. Morris The characters of the group $GL_n(q)$, Math. Zeitscher, 1963, 112-123.

**5**.Pharm Huu Tiep, A. E. Zalesski, Minimal characters of the finite classical groups, Comm in algebra, 1995, 2093-2167.

Comment: $;-){}{}{}{}{}{}{}{}$

Answer (score 0):

There is e.g. a [monograph by R.Carter](http://books.google.co.uk/books/about/Finite_Groups_of_Lie_Type.html?id=LvvuAAAAMAAJ&redir_esc=y), and this has been treated in a number of other books, too.